# How do I shift Google Sheets duration value from 35:55:00 to 0:35:55?

Tags: google-sheets

I have pasted multiple run duration values from Garmin into a Google Sheet. The longer runs (> 1 hour) copy/paste correctly. Eg: 2:10:35. The problem is shorter (< 1 hour) runs. Eg 35:55. The latter are being shown in Google Sheets as 35:55:00. Ie Google assumes 35:55 is 35 hours and 55 mins, not 35 mins and 55 seconds. So for my shorter sub 1 hour durations I need an easy way to convert 35:55:00 to 0:35:55.

Comment: I don't see how you could tell which is which given the information you've provided, e.g. 2:10:00 could be showing a value of 2 hours 10 minutes correctly or 2 minutes 10 seconds incorrectly?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. Google sheets was showing 2:10:00 correctly as 2 hours 10 mins. It was showing 35:55:00 incorrectly - should have been 0:35:55. The answer below from Crazy Ivan worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Tom Sharpe said, there is some room for interpretation in the data you have. But assuming that the duration of your runs is always between 10 minutes and 10 hours, we can disambiguate the values as follows:

```
=if(A1 > 10/24, A1/60, A1)
```

Numerically, the duration values are measured in days, so A1 > 10/24 means "more than 10 hours". In this case the value gets divided by 60.

Depending on your workout regime you may want to replace the threshold of 10 by another number; perhaps it's safer to say that the runs are always between 5 minutes and 5 hours.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks!